# Is an http.Request.Body buffered in golang?

Tags: security, http, go

I'm writing a web app in Go. I have a http.Handler that does some stuff and writes a response.

```
func (h *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

So far I don't do anything different between POST and GET requests which is fine in the usual case.

But POSTs have a `Request.Body`.

What happens to that POST data? Does go buffer it? Is my handler invoked immediately, or does it wait until the POST is fully received?

---

To provide some context, I am specifically concerned with a [slow loris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris_(software)) attack.

I know that go has a very low per-connection overhead, but what about POSTing large amounts of data? If I POST 9Mb of data and then spoon-feed 1 byte at a time, how does go deal with that? Did it buffer the 9Mb in memory? If I do 10,000 such requests, that could be 90Gb of buffered POST data. My server won't like that very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is some buffering involved, but the handler is invoked immediately, and it's up to you to read the request.Body.

As far as resource consumption from slow clients and specifically attacks like slowloris, the easiest solution is to set a [ReadTimeout](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) on your server.

Comment: So if I don't do anything with request.Body (like my naive handler) and start writing a response, does go discard those request.Body bytes? I thought that the entire request needs to be read before you can start writing back on the TCP connection.

Comment: No, the client will get blocked when the buffers fill, and TCP back pressure stops them from sending more. The go server will gladly write the response for you immediately, but most clients don't read concurrently and won't see it while they're trying to send. If you're expecting a body, you should read it if you want clients to get the response.

Comment: Thanks I think that helps. So without the ReadTimeout, everything just kind of deadlocks? The client waits for the server to receive, and the server waits for the client to receive? And the server has a few kB in a buffer somewhere?

Comment: It could if your response is large enough. Between the buffered io and the tcp buffers on both sides, simple responses will get sent right away.